# OAuth Web Api2 RefreshToken

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I'm trying to implement Owin Authentication on my Web Api, below is my code

```
var options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions 
{   AllowInsecureHttp    = true,    
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString(AppSettings.OAuthTokenEndpoint),             
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),   
    Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),   
    AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(AppSettings.JwtIssuer)                            }; 
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
```

I'm creating access token valid for 10mins.

Basically i need,if the user is ideal for 10 mins , API needs to rejects the call. If the user not in idle i need to refresh my token and allow them to access API.
How can i achieve this?